# Ruby variable from an external shell command

Tags: ruby, shell, operating-system, rubygems, haml

I’m using a gem called artii ( http://rubygems.org/gems/artii ) that creates ascii art images from text.

I can only seem to call it using system(), however I’d like to display the result as text in a webpage

My .rb file:

```
def makeText
  @word = system('artii Hello World')
  puts @word
  @word
end
```

result of `puts`:

```
=>  _    _      _ _       
=> | |  | |    | | |       
=> | |__| | ___| | | ___  
=> |  __  |/ _ \ | |/ _ \ 
=> | |  | |  __/ | | (_) |
=> |_|  |_|\___|_|_|\___/
```

Then, in my haml file:

```
#{makeText} 
=> true
```

Is there a way to take the result from the command line and convert it to a string, array, or hash to display in a webpage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [backticks](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-60) rather than the `system` method. Just enclose your shell command in backticks, and the return value will be a string containing whatever it output to standard out.

```
@word = `artii Hello World`
```

Note: Be careful not to pass user input to the shell without sanitizing it first, to prevent malicious users from executing arbitrary shell commands. As long as you're the one supplying the string in backticks, and not the user, you're fine.

Comment: Great, thanks! Now I have a string but with the line returns removed - I’ve tried using `String.split(“n”)` as well as `\r\n`
Any further help appreciated.

Comment: Do you want an array of lines? Then the command you're looking for is  `@word.split("\n")`. `"\n"` is newline, the default string separator (in most cases).

Comment: finally got it... had to use `word.split(“\\n”)` then `gsub(/\n/, '<br />’)` to insert line breaks for the html, and `input.gsub(" ", '&nbsp;’)` to take care of whitespace
Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

It seems ridiculous to me to call the *gem* as external command, either using `system` or backticks. You can use it from Ruby as a Ruby library, without any system interaction. The simplest invocation would be:

```
@word = Artii::Base.asciify('Hello World')
```

If you want more complex invocation (i.e. different fonts, styles, etc), then check out [that gem's documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/artii/frames).